# Scrollbars covers data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My treeview data last row is covered by the bottom scrollbar

I googled everywhere, no answers found

```py
root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
scrollbar_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient='horizontal', command=tree.xview)
scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(tree, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
scrollbar_horizontal.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
scrollbar_vertical.pack(side='right', fill='y')
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar_horizontal.set, yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set)
```

I dont want the scrollbar to cover my last row

am i missing something.

[image: What it looks like]

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `tree` as the parent of your scrollbars. Change them back to the `root` window and use `grid` instead:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.grid(row=0,column=0)
scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
scrollbar_vertical.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
scrollbar_horizontal = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=tree.xview)
scrollbar_horizontal.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set,xscrollcommand=scrollbar_horizontal.set)

header = "ABCDEFG"
tree["columns"] = [i for i in header]

for i in range(len(header)):
    tree.column(header[i], width=100, minwidth=50, anchor="w",stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.heading(header[i], text=header[i], anchor='w')

for i in range(15):
    tree.insert("",0,values=[i for i in header])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No it still does the same

Comment: @JacquesCelliers I have added dummy data to my sample above - it clearly shows the last row without being covered.